# Java error when I try to create an object with a constructor with a string parameter

Tags: java, string, object, indexing, constructor

I created two constructors in my Move class, one with two `int` parameter and one with `String` parameter:

```
public Move(int row,int col)
{
  int[] [] Move = new int[row][col]; 
}   
public Move(String r)
{       
 String move = new String(r);    
}
```

Then I try making an object:

```
Move m = new Move(1,1);
m = new Move("E1");
  //The second one does not work and I get this as an error in java:

  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
at Move.<init>(Move.java:16)
at moveTester.main(moveTester.java:10)
```

how do I fix it, thank you!

Comment: Your stack trace disagrees with your claims. Please provide a [mcve] and explain why you think the exception shouldn't happen.

Comment: Also note: the code you are showing is nonsensical. You assign values to two local variables. Those variables only exist within the body of that constructor. When the constructor is done executing, these local variables will vanish, they are no longer accessible from other code. It is also a super strange idea to name variables move and Move within a class named Move. Use lower case for variables, and give them distinctive meaningful names!

Comment: I have to respect the name from the UML and the Move class this was not my whole file

Comment: public class Move
{
   private int row;
   private int col;
   
   //constructor
   public Move(int row,int col)
   {
   this.row();
   this.col();
      int[] [] Move = new int[row][col]; 
   }
   
   public Move(String r)
   {    
     String move = r;      
   }
   
  public int row()
    {
       return row;
    }
   
   public int col()
   {
      return col;
   }
  
}

Comment: @mpl post that in your question body, and also where is main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a `String` parameter, you can use it as it is, you do not need to create a new one, see:

```
public Move(String r)
{       
 String move = r;    
}
```

However, `move` will only be a local variable, you probably want something different, but that's another step, which you will need to do after this one.